# "Alt" bindings not working in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

When I bind my text widget to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, the function assigned to that binding does not get called.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def func(event):
    print("Hello world")
    return 'break'

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.bind("<Control-Alt-d>" , func)

mainloop()
```

Here, when I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> combination on my keyboard, the function "`func`" does not get called.

This problem does not seem to occur when I don't bind the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys together - ie `"<Alt-d>"`. This really confuses me.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: it does work pretty well for me. try again.

Comment: Try changing `"<Control-Alt-d>"` to `"<Control-Alt-KeyPress-d>"`. I had that same problem a while ago. I have no idea why it solved my problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard not related to this question. Just about the edit you made. Can I know why `master=window` is necessary for control variables?

Comment: @JacksonPro Basically for the fact that with more than one window, the variables wont know where to exist from.

Comment: @CoolCloud I didn't get that. Can you elaborate or is there documentation where I can read more?

Comment: @TheLizzard: Thanks! I changed the binding accordingly and it works fine now.

Comment: @JacksonPro Tkinter has a `_deafult_root` variable that gets updated to the first `Tk()` object that the user creates. If a user has more than 1 `Tk()` objects they must add the `master` parameter to all widgets (usually the first argument as in `<Widget>(master, ...)`). That is why I added `master=window` in case someone uses multiple `Tk()` instances. It isn't documented on effibot. All it says is this: *"The constructor argument is only relevant if you’re running Tkinter with multiple Tk instances"*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it worked for me but if its not working for you then change `text.bind("<Control-Alt-d>" , func)` to `text.bind("<Control-Alt-KeyPress-d>" , func)` or maybe you should try again in different directory

Comment: Why a *different directory*? Also I already  wrote "*Try changing "<Control-Alt-d>" to "<Control-Alt-KeyPress-d>"*" in the comments and OP said it worked. It isn't good to take someone else's answer without even giving them credit.